# rails server (WEbrick) eventually stops logging to stdout on Mac?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, macos, logging, console, webrick

If this is a real problem, I'd expect to find it here or in Google, but I seem to be the only one experiencing it:

After leaving our plain-vanilla Rails app running for a few hours or days on my development laptop, I'll discover that there's no new output to stdout (which usually mirrors the development.log output).  The server is still responsive, as I can make HTTP requests to it and it'll serve responses, and I can successfully close that server and start up a new one without clearing my Terminal tab.

This is Rails 3.0.9, WEbrick 1.3.1, ruby 1.9.2 (2011-02-18), OS X 10.6.7.

Has anyone else run into to this?  My instinct is to just switch to Mongrel, but we have a development team of 6 others, and they're hesitant to switch underlying infastructure just because of a non-reproducible problem on one machine that may or not be fixed by switching...

Comment: I am experiencing the same thing using `Thin` webserver

Answer (score 1):

I have had the exact same thing on Ubuntu (Linux). It happens when I put the computer to sleep. The solution is to kill the server first.